# How to just deploy jar from Maven?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, deployment, pom.xml

Actually I deploy my projects on the server with Maven ("mvn deploy"), I would like to just deploy jar and not the files md5, sha1, xml ...

For the connection I use :

```
<distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>myID</id>
            <url>scp://myURL/url>
        </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

and

```
<extensions>
    <extension>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </extension>
</extensions>
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Why? These additional files are part of the maven repository ecosystem.

Comment: I would like to deploy several jar on a single folder

Comment: I think you are mixing thing. The deploy phase of maven is **only** to deploy into a maven repository. If you want to do something else, the correct way would be to do this somewhere else. For example you could create a separate module which has your jars as dependencies and use `dependency:copy-dependencies` to download them into your target folder.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your need, this could be for you ...

Visit http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html